# Suppressing www hostname and forcing HTTPS in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, http-redirect

I‘m trying to force my website to load via `https://` and supressing the `www.` hostname in my `.htaccess` file located in the topmost public directory.

`mod_rewrite` is on. I know that this is easily possible in PHP but I’m trying to do this in my `.htaccess` file.

Here is my approach:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+)$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This works in Google Chrome (37.0.2062.124) what kinda surprises me since I thought the whole process is handled on the server side and should behave the same way on the client side.

I have also tried to use `%{HTTPS} =off` and `%{HTTPS} !=on` instead of checking the port.